# gmpy2: How do I track precision of mpc operations?

Tags: python, math, precision, gmp

Say I have two `gmpy2.mpc` objects `x` and `y` precise to p bits. When I compute `x+y` it may be that some parts of x and y cancel so I'm left with less precision.

For example

```
from gmpy2 import *

x = mpc('-0.55555')
y = mpc('0.5555500000001')
print(x+y)
```

The result is precise to only 4 significant figures even though `x` and `y` were precise to ~15.

I think I need to work out how many bits of cancellation occur when I do addition and subtraction and then take this away from the minimum of `x` or `y`'s precision. For multiplication and division I think I will only lose 1 bit of precision at most.

So the question is quite general: how can I keep track of the precision of `mpc` objects, particularly when adding and subtracting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will return the numbers of matching bits of two `mpfr` objects.

```
import gmpy2

def matching_bits(x, y):
    '''Returns the number of bits that match between x and y. The
    sign of x and y are ignored. x and y must be of type mpfr.'''

    # Force both values to be positive, and x >= y.
    x = abs(x)
    y = abs(y)
    if x < y:
        x, y = y, x

    if not isinstance(x, type(gmpy2.mpfr(0))) or not isinstance(y, type(gmpy2.mpfr(0))):
        raise TypeError("Arguments must be of type 'mpfr'.")

    x_bits, x_exp, x_prec = x.digits(2)
    y_bits, y_exp, y_prec = y.digits(2)

    # (x_exp - y_exp) is the number of zeros that must be prepended
    # to x to align the mantissas. If that is greater than the precision
    # y, then no bits in common.
    if (x_exp - y_exp) > x_prec:
        return 0

    x_bits = "0" * (x_exp - y_exp) + x_bits

    count = 0
    while count < min(x_prec, y_prec) and x_bits[count] == y_bits[count]:
        count += 1
    return count
```

I haven't extensively tested this function but it should give you a start. You will need to check the real and imaginary components separately. You'll probably want to modify it to check for sign and whether you are performing addition vs. subtraction.